# Ruby: How to issue CLI commands on Windows

Tags: windows, ruby, command-line

I'm new to Ruby, so this may be a pretty basic question.

I have a Windows batch file that I use all the time to interface with my source control system .  The batch file issues various command-line commands supported by the source control system's command line interface (CLI).

I'd like to write a Ruby program that issues some of these commands. In general, how do you issue command-line commands from a Ruby program on Windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to run a system (command line)  command  in ruby wrap it with  `

for example

```
puts `dir`
```

will run the  `cmd` window  `dir` command

if you need the return value (`ERRORLEVEL`) you can use the `system` command

for example `system("dir")`  which return a `true`  for success and `false` for failure    the `ERRORLEVEL` value  is stored at `$?`

Comment: Thanks Alon!  I tried, puts 'dir', but this just printed the string "dir". I wonder if I'm doing something wrong. Your second suggestion of, system("dir"), seemed to do the trick!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you, as for the first option its not '  its should be `  that is ASCII char 96

Answer (score 1):

```
task :build do
  command_line = "gcc ..."
  `#{command_line}`
end
```

Answer (score 0):

http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/05/automating-windows-shell-with-ruby.html

and for scripting:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell